# How to sort excel column using int64index?

Tags: python, excel

I am very new to Python and still trying to figure out the basics. I am trying to sort my excel files by a specific column. I do not want to introduce headers to my excel file and I have int64Index as names of my columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
df=pd.read_table(r"E:\miceFCG\XY\SRR15890912_rmdup_bowtie_mm39_sorted_bowtie_tryhard_minus_bottom.bed")
df.to_excel('XYtest.xlsx', 'Sheet1', index=False, header=None)
newdf=pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\TranMinhNgoc\Box\Belancio_Lab\Misc\MiceFCG\XX\XYtest.xlsx", 'Sheet1', header=None)
print(newdf)
print(newdf.columns)
newdf.sort_values(5)
```

And this is my result

```
   0         1         2          3  4  5    6     7         8
0     chr1   3134712   3141382   UID-9194  -  0    0  6670  0.000000
1     chr1   3176141   3182815   UID-9195  -  2  128  6674  0.019179
2     chr1   3307788   3314490   UID-9491  -  0    0  6702  0.000000
3     chr1   3686012   3692682   UID-9197  -  2  116  6670  0.017391
4     chr1   3765623   3771899   UID-9687  -  0    0  6276  0.000000
...    ...       ...       ...        ... .. ..  ...   ...       ...
9255  chrY  30308484  30315141  UID-17429  -  0    0  6657  0.000000
9256  chrY  32071900  32078557  UID-17428  -  0    0  6657  0.000000
9257  chrY  33976103  33982760  UID-17427  -  0    0  6657  0.000000
9258  chrY  58369723  58376380  UID-17426  -  0    0  6657  0.000000
9259  chrY  59435719  59442460  UID-17425  -  0    0  6741  0.000000

[9260 rows x 9 columns]
Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
```

However, the excel sheet is never sorted by column 5 as I wanted and I could not figure out why. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Just to confirm, it looks like from `newdf.sort_values(5)` that you aren't saving or printing the results of the sort. Unless you add `inplace=True`, the original dataframe won't be changed.

Comment: Yes, sorry it's my bad, I did not print the sort result of `newdf.sort_values(5)` . I also tried `newdf.sort_values(5, inplace=True)` but it also did not change anything

Comment: Did this work for you? `print(newdf.sort_values(5))`. You are logging it before sort. Just making sure, if you are looking at right place. Please refer https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html